# Why does this EF property return another property's value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I just ran across a curious issue in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application. I created an Entity Framework model which includes object `A`:

[image: Object definition]

Property `PK` is an int, while `ID` is a GUID.

I then attempted to add `ID` to `A`'s edit page as an editable field. When using `@Html.EditorFor()` or `@Html.TextBoxFor()`, the value in the resulting textbox was the value of the `PK` property, not `ID`. Using `@Html.DisplayFor()` properly displays the `ID` as a GUID.

**Code:**

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID)
</div>

<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ID)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ID)
</div>
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

After playing around with it a bit, I decided to simply change the name of the `ID` property. The edit fields immediately began showing the proper GUID value.

**What is causing this behavior?** Is `ID` a reserved property name for the primary key in Entity Framework, or does it conflict with some MVC naming convention (in the style of `xxxController`)?

Comment: By Default Entity Will assume that ID is your PK. You can change this w/ Fluent API. That's why changing the name worked.

Comment: @Dunbar: Please add your comment as an answer. The OP is not going to get a better one.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Will do, Thanks Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Default Entity Will assume that ID is your PK. You can change this w/ Fluent API. That's why changing the name worked.

Here is a good write up on configuring your mapping with fluent: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx

- Moving comment as Answer for benefit of the post. -

Comment: All correct, but how does that explain why `EditorFor` and `DisplayFor` for the same property `ID` show totally different values?

Comment: What do your editor and display templates looks like? My guess is something is going on under the hood of those.

Comment: I cannot tell, I'm not the question owner :) He would need to have an editor template for a `Guid` (like `Guid.cshtml`) if the templates should cause a problem. But then it's still strange why *renaming* the property *without changing its type* should have any effect on the display.

Comment: Lol I thought you were the OP ;)  I think the types must be the same.